# In Google Apps Script, how can I set the HTTP response code for a service I implement?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-codes

Say I have "service" returning a XML document:

```
function doGet() {
    var result = '<result>42</result>';
    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
    output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
    return output;
}
```

By default, the HTTP status code for the response will be 200. How can I set it something different, say 500 (while still returning the same XML document)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the ContentService. Implicitly, only the 200 status code can be returned back by the successfully completion of the script. Other error codes are all system level that get raised when something goes wrong.

If you have a good use case for this, please open a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Got it. I imagine this can be useful every time the code doesn't "blow up", but instead detects an error which warrants a 500 response code. Being able to set the response code is commonly a part of the API for a "response" class, in fact so common that I am not sure this warrants the description of a use case ;).

Comment: There is now a request in the issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3151

Comment: @mzimmerman I tried throwing an exception, but that still returns a 200 and some html text.  Not super useful when the XML document is being consumed by a service.

Comment: Wow, this is still the correct answer today :-( (The feature request has been migrated to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759757)