# Return a 500 error from doPost in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, zapier, http-status-code-500

I have doPost(e) function in an App Script that is called by Zapier. If an exception occurs in my code, a 200 response is sent back to Zapier, but I'd like it to return a 500 error, so that Zapier knows it has failed.

```
function doPost(e) {
  if (e) {
    try {
      switch (e.parameter.action) {
        case 'newOrder':
          processNewOrder(e.parameter.orderId, e.parameter.orderType);
          break;
        case 'cancelledOrder':
          processCancelledOrder(e.parameter.orderId, e.parameter.orderType);
          break;
      }

      return ContentService.createTextOutput('Done');
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I return an exception to Zapier in that catch?

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

Currently, you cannot force the script to return response codes other than 200.

#### Issue Tracker:

This has been reported previously in Issue Tracker:

- [Allow scripts to send response codes other than 200](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759757)

I'd suggest you to star the referenced issue, in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.

#### Workarounds:

Therefore, you'll have to come up with other ways to return information regarding the outcome of the response, like the one suggested by [Amit Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973250). But the response code will always be 200.

#### Related question:

- [In Google Apps Script, how can I set the HTTP response code for a service I implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15235783)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

With:

```
    }
    catch (err) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(err.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does that send 500?